# Implicit conversion to templated struct?

Tags: c++, templates, implicit-conversion, template-argument-deduction

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct Foo {
  T var;

  Foo (const T& val){
    var = val;
  }
};

template <typename T>
void print(Foo<T> func){}

int main() {
  Foo f=3;
  print(f); // Works
  print(3); // Doesn't work
}
```

`f` is a well defined instance of `Foo`, so obviously it works. But since 3 is convertible (implicitly, I believe) to `Foo`, why doesn't `print(3);` work?

If it's not an implicit conversion, how could I make it so?

I would really like to avoid `print(Foo(3));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Template argument deduction won't consider implicit conversions. To get the desired call syntax, you could add an overload for `print` like this

```
template <typename T>
void print(T a)        // selected if T is not a Foo specialization
{
    print(Foo{a});     // call print with a Foo explicitly
}
```

If the argument to `print` is already a specialization of `Foo`, the overload taking a `Foo<T>` will be selected.

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Pb19oK7rE).

Answer (score 1):

Implicit conversion (from `int` to `Foo<int>`) won't be considered in template argument deduction, the template parameter `T` can't be deduced and then the invocation fails.

Beside `print(Foo(3));`, you can specify the template argument explicitly to bypass template argument deduction, e.g.

```
print<int>(3);
```